# How to check if wp7 XNA touch event is within a defined rectangle

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I want to check if a user click is within a set of retangles I have defined, but should I do it another way to do this check?

This is what I have now, but I am in doubt how to compare the rectangle object with the touches object

```
private bool CheckEnemyClicked(Vector2 vector2, out Enemy enemyOut)
{
    TouchCollection touches = TouchPanel.GetState();

    foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
    {
        //Find the rectangle of the sprite
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
                                  (int)enemy.Position.X, 
                                  (int)enemy.Position.Y, 
                                  enemy.Width, 
                                  enemy.Height);

        //Check if click is hitting enemy
        if(touchinput is within rectangle)
        {
            enemyOut = enemy;
            return true;
        }
    }
    enemyOut = null;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TouchCollection returns a collection of TouchLocation objects which has a "Position" member. Rectangle has a Contains method which has an overload that can check if a particular point is contained within it. So the XNA framework does all the hard work for you.

Your code would look something like this for the collision checking part for Touch.

```
//Check if click is hitting enemy
foreach (TouchLocation location in collection)
{
     if (rectangle.Contains((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y))
     {
          enemyOut = enemy;
          return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`TouchCollection` is a collection of touch points (as user may be touching the screen in several places). You should check for the individual touch points within the `TouchCollection` and find the position of those relative to your enemy rectangle.

Comment: So make a for loop and check all points? that would be 10000 (100x100 pixels) operations per sprite I am checking, thats not an issue if I have 10-20 sprites on the screen and do that 30 times per second?

Comment: You need some kind of scene management. A Quadtree comes to my mind, which can be difficult with animated objects. But you also only need to check all visible objects, whats not on the screen can not be touched. Now you just iterate over all user touches, make a test against the visible objects in the Quadtree cell and you decreased the tests to a minimum. Of course you only test per pixel if you made sure that this particular touch was inside the sprite rect.